# 050 + at the beginning of verified signature

Tags: ios, object, cryptography, openssl, rsa

I am using OpenSSL in iOS app to sign a message. I use RSA_sign to sign. When I use RSA_verify to verify the signature, result is like this

> 050   +(f2d7846a5f495a743e470663facf7a2858d052cf

Where f2d7846a5f495a743e470663facf7a2858d052cf is the original signature. So I am getting additional 050    +( at the beginning of the signature. Can anyone please tell me the reason of this?

This is how I am signing

```
int sign = RSA_sign(NID_sha1,( char *)reply, strlen(reply), signature, &siglen, myRSA );
```

where reply contains sha1 hashed data to be signed.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm very surprised that you see anything other than the original signature in the buffer. `RSA_verify` is not supposed to "return" anything other than the result of the verification (in the returned integer value, `0` for failure, `1` for success. Please use the methods as defined in the [SSL documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_sign.html).

In my opinion it is a bug that you can see the hash in the first place. Unfortunately OpenSSL is not very well documented.

Comment: Anything missing from my answer, Aqueel? Relying on the returned hash may be dangerous, it may change in the implementation as it is not part of the documented interface.